# Construct loop with multiple conditions

Tags: r

Say I have a set

```
M = c(-1.64, 1.99, 0.79, 1.72, 1.07, 2.12, 1.98, 0.12)
```

I want to make a for loop that contains an if statement depending on two conditions. If there exists numbers `m_1, m_2, m_3` in `M` such that

`-1/2 <= m_1 < m_2 < m_3 <= 10` and  `m_3-m_1 <= 1/2`.

Then I want the statement `k = 1` to happen, otherwise I want `k = 0`. My first try/instinct was this:

```
for (i in 1:7){
    if (-0.5 <= M[i] && M[i] < M[i+1] && M[i+1] < M[i+2] && M[i+2] <= 10 &&  (M[i+2]-M[i]) <= 1/2) {
      k = 1
    } else 
      k = 0  
}
```

But now I realize that if, for example, `i=6`, then `M[8]` is computed, which does not exist… is there any way around this?

I also think that it's not enough with one for loop like that but I need 3 nested for loops with different indexes, but that sounds like a mess.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow doesn't like LaTeX syntax. Could you try reformatting using syntactically valid code where possible? It's nice to provide a reproducible example (with values!) so since we don't have `a`,`a_2`, ... it is much more useful if you say "I have a set `M = c(1, 8, 11, 12, 13)`" than `M = (a, a_2, ..., a_7)` which is pretty useless.

Comment: For your first condition, I would suggest *sorting* `M`. Then find the first element of the sorted `M` that satisfies `M >  -1/2` and look at all the subsequent entries that are less than 10. Then you can test if any of them satisfy condition 2.

Comment: @Gregor - Thanks for your input, give me a few minutes I'll edit the question!

Comment: Unfortunately, without an example (or 3), it's difficult to help. Ideally, you would provide 3 or 4 small sample inputs, along with your epxected result for each of them. Something like `M1 = seq(0.1, 0.5, by = 0.1)` (what is your expected output for this), then `M2 = 0:6` (your condition is not met, what is your expected output), and maybe one more, something closer to an edge case  `M3 = c(-5, 0, 4, 4.1, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 10)`

Comment: @Gregor - does the updated question make things clearer now?

Comment: Better, but what is your expected output? Just a `k = 1` at the end because numbers meeting your criteria exist? Do you care to know which numbers meet the criteria?

Comment: the thing is, M is generated randomly from an exponential distribution. So I want to do that for-loop above 1000 times, and then I want to place all the zeros and ones in an array p and then compute the mean of k. So for every of these 1000 iterations, I'm gonna get a new M each time. so I only care for if k=1 or k=0 and then place all these in an array and then I want to compute the mean of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only items of `M` that matter are the ones between your thresholds, -0.5 and 10. So we'll get rid of everything else, and sort what remains. Then we need to take the difference between elements offset by 2 and see if any of those are less than your 0.5 difference threshold:

```
M = c(-1.64, 1.99, 0.79, 1.72, 1.07, 2.12, 1.98, 0.12)
sub_m = sort(M[M >= -.5 & M <= 10])
any(tail(sub_m,-2) - head(sub_m,-2) <= 0.5)
# [1] TRUE
```

We can wrap this up in a handy function:

```
foo = function(M) {
  sub_m = sort(M[M >= -.5 & M <= 10])
  any(tail(sub_m, -2) - head(sub_m, -2) <= 0.5)
}

foo(1:10)
# [1] FALSE
foo(M)
# [1] TRUE
```

I'd recommend testing it on some additional cases. I've written the function to return a `logical` true or false, you can use `as.integer` on it if you'd prefer to have a numeric result. You could also parametrize the function to optionally input different thresholds.

`tail(sub_m, -2)` is all but the first two elements of `sub_m`. `head(sub_m, -2)` is all but the last two elements. So `tail(sub_m,-2) - head(sub_m,-2)` is a vectorized way to calculate `c(sub_m[3] - sub_m[1], sub_m[4] - sub_m[2], ...)`.

Comment: Thank you endlessly for this man! I will ponder and think a bit now. I'll return with any question that I have. Here is an upvote meanwhile.

Comment: Ok, I now understand the any, tail and head functions you have used! No need for numeric results only the boolean since I just want to count some occurrences. Thank you very much @Gregor!